# Row not found or changed error while executing LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

This is my code

```
        using (BatchDashboardDataContext db = new BatchDashboardDataContext())
        {
            TBatchDashboard b = new TBatchDashboard();

            b.Id = deletedBatchId;
            db.TBatchDashboards.Attach(b);
            db.TBatchDashboards.DeleteOnSubmit(b);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

Id is the primary key of `TBatchDashboard` table. Also there is a record having `deletedBatchId` value as the primary key in `TBatchDashboard` table.
Please check it give me advices.
Thanks.

Comment: Instead of attaching the object, if you query it as in: `TBatchDashboard b = db.TBatchDashboards.First(i => i.Id == d`eletedBatchId);`  does it work?